# How to link a script to a button in startup.py

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-3

I created a startup.py file in order to customize my toolbar.
In particular, I would like to create buttons that could launch my various scripts that I created.

So I defined an icon to display it on my toolbar (it works!)

```
ExportMap = QAction(QIcon("ExportAsPNG.png"), "ExportLayoutAsPNG", iface.mainWindow())
ExportMap.setCheckable(False)
iface.addToolBarIcon(ExportMap)
```

But I cannot link my script to the icon

I tried to import it with this command :

`import profiles/default/processing/scripts/ExportMapPNG.py as script`

And I added this at the end of creating the icon :

`action.triggered.connect(script)`

But it doesn't seem to work.

How I can link my icon to my script ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `startup.py` file, add the following

```py
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
import demo
```

Copy the following file `demo.py` content to the same directory as the `startup.py` file with

```py
import base64
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QAction
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import (QPixmap, QIcon)
from qgis.utils import iface
import processing

def output_demo():
    print('demo')
    # processing.execAlgorithmDialog('native:package')
    processing.execAlgorithmDialog('yournamespace:youralgoname')
    # Can take parameters to prefill the GUI fields
    # processing.execAlgorithmDialog('yournamespace:youralgoname', parameters={})

# via command
# base64 -w 0 myimage.png # My image is 32x32
base64_data = "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"

pm1 = QPixmap()
pm1.loadFromData(base64.b64decode(base64_data))
demo_action = QAction(
    QIcon(pm1),
    'Output demo',
)
demo_action.triggered.connect(output_demo)
toolbar1 = iface.addToolBar('Demo action')
toolbar1.setObjectName('Demo action')
toolbar1.addAction(demo_action)
```

Then, restart QGIS to see a Wikipedia icon. Open the PyQGIS console and click on the Wikipedia icon to see an output "demo" text in the PyQGIS console.

With this, change the simple logic within `output_demo` function to do what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply ! Unfortunately that's not quite what I want to do. My script already exists and is declared by a class (`class ExportLayoutAlgorithm (QgsProcessingAlgorithm):`). This is not a script that I can use without `initAlgorithm` and `processAlgorithm`. I would like to link this script (which I can access through the Processing Toolbox) to my button/icon

Comment: Updated. you can just try running `processing.execAlgorithmDialog('native:package')` to see it open the algorithm windows as long as it's registered

Comment: So I tried with `processing.execAlgorithmDialog('profiles\default\processing\scripts:ExportMapPNG.py')` but nothing happens when clicking on the icon. Did I have to put the `.py` file or the name of the class of my script ? And is it necessary to put the link of the folder where the script is located instead of the `native` ?

Comment: Not normally, you script is already available. In your processing script, `def name(self):` return a value. It's this one you need to use with prefix `script:`not a path

Comment: Indeed I tried with `execAlgorithmDialog('script:export_layout_png')` and it worked! Thanks a lot for your help !